# I have problems generating the budle and I get this. app:minifyReleaseWithR8

Tags: android-app-bundle

> Task :app:minifyReleaseWithR8
> AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"Missing classes detected while running R8. Please add the missing classes or apply additional keep rules that are generated in C:\Users\NAME-PC\AndroidStudioProjects\NAME(APP)\app\build\outputs\mapping\release\missing_rules.txt.\n","sources":[{}]}
> AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"Missing class com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLParametersImpl (referenced from: void org.conscrypt.KitKatPlatformOpenSSLSocketImplAdapter.(org.conscrypt.AbstractConscryptSocket))\r\nMissing class org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.SSLParametersImpl (referenced from: void org.conscrypt.PreKitKatPlatformOpenSSLSocketImplAdapter.(org.conscrypt.AbstractConscryptSocket))\r\nMissing class sun.security.x509.X509Key (referenced from: void net.i2p.crypto.eddsa.EdDSAEngine.engineInitVerify(java.security.PublicKey))","sources":[{}],"tool":"R8"}
> Missing classes detected while running R8. Please add the missing classes or apply additional keep rules that are generated in C:\Users\NAME-PC\AndroidStudioProjects\NAME(APP)\app\build\outputs\mapping\release\missing_rules.txt.

Missing class com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLParametersImpl (referenced from: void org.conscrypt.KitKatPlatformOpenSSLSocketImplAdapter.(org.conscrypt.AbstractConscryptSocket))
Missing class org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.SSLParametersImpl (referenced from: void org.conscrypt.PreKitKatPlatformOpenSSLSocketImplAdapter.(org.conscrypt.AbstractConscryptSocket))
Missing class sun.security.x509.X509Key (referenced from: void net.i2p.crypto.eddsa.EdDSAEngine.engineInitVerify(java.security.PublicKey))

When generating the bundle I get this error, how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add the latest version dependence. for example...
if you add this 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.5.0' dependence. replace the latest version "4.5.0" -> to -> "4.11.0"